# Get Spreadsheets from a folder and modify them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a folder called "Adform" in my Drive and I want to take all the spreadsheets from there and modify them by adding new columns, change headers.
At this point I managed to get the files name, one by one, but I don't know how to use SpreadSheetApp to modify those Spreadsheets.

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Adform');
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      var files = folders.next().getFiles();
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        Logger.log(file.getName());
     
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### How to loop through all the Spreadsheets in a Drive folder

You are almost there. The best way in my opinion is to check if the mime type of the file is `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`, and if so, get the `id`. Then pass this id to another function that will modify the Spreadsheet in any way that you want.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Adform');
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      var files = folders.next().getFiles();
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        // Check if file is a spreadsheet
        if (file.getMimeType() === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
          // Call the function to modify the spreadsheet with the file id
          modifySpreadhsheet(file.getId())
        }
    }
  }
}

function modifySpreadsheet(id) {
  // Open the file with the id
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  // Get all the sheets
  var sheets = file.getSheets()
  // Get the first sheet
  var firstSheet = sheets[0]
  // Get the range that contains all the data in that sheet
  var range = firstSheet.getDataRange();
  // Get all the values in that range
  var values = range.getValues();

  Logger.log(values)
}
```

This sample function will just get the first sheet of the spreadsheet and then Log all the data within that spreadsheet to the logger.

Then you can use functions like [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setValues(Object)) to modify the content as needed.

#### References

- [getMimeType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getMimeType())
- [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getId())
- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())
- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getDataRange())
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())