# How to convert my google spreadsheet container-bound script to code standalone script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working code that bound into a spreadsheet. I want to run this script to other spreadsheet automatically without me opening the spreadsheet and opening the apps script editor one by one. I have read online that I must change my script into standalone script. Here is my code :

```js
function hideRows() {
  let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let ss = sh.getSheetByName("Invoice");
  let r = ss.getRange("A2:G23");
  let data = r.getValues();
  //console.log(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].filter(String).length == 0) {
      ss.hideRows(i + 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything I can do? my coding skill is below basic, and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a new script from `https://script.new` and paste your Apps Script code in the editor.

Since this is a standalone script, the following line needs to be replaced.

```js
let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

It should be replaced with the URL or ID of the Google Sheet.

```js
const ssId = "1234...";
let sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
```

Comment: Another option is to use the Drive Service to retrieve the file object, i.e. by searching  , then use `SpreadsheetApp.open(file)`.

Comment: @Rubén can you explain how to use the drive Service to retrieve the file object? thankyou

Comment: @Amit Agarwal, thankyou for your answer, I can run the code without any error, but I need to change the ssID for every spreadsheet, how can I change all the sheets in one folder? thankyou

Comment: @StevenD See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67599199/1595451